# File.exists() return false using javaservice.exe

Tags: java, file-exists, java-service-wrapper

I have the following Java code to check if exists the remote directory: "\\server_web\\Covers"

```
File CoversPathFile = new File(Options.CoversPath);
if (!CoversPathFile.getAbsoluteFile().exists()) throw new Exception();
```

It works well when the execution is through command line or a .Bat file,
But if I use the [JavaService.exe](http://javaservice.ow2.org/docs/devdocs/devcmds.html) to wrap the java class in a Windows service, the File.exists() method returns false;

The problem doesn't occurs if a Local Path is used.

It's JavaService.exe bug?

JavaService.exe version: 2.0.10.0
Platform: Windows 2008
Java versión: 8.0_40

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a current work directory. Because you are using relativ path names. Starting from a batch makes the start path to the current working path. Therefore you can use the -current option to provide a path:

> **-current current_dir (optional)** - A directory to use as the current working directory for the service. If this parameter is specified, all
>   relative paths in the service will be relative to relative to the
>   specified directory.

See also here:

http://javaservice.ow2.org/docs/devdocs/devcmds.html

---

Update:

If you are accessing a remote resource, the user assigned to the service does not have the privileges to access that resource.

To  change the permission, you have to assign a specific user to your service. As default a service runs on the local service user account. Change this to an proper user.

Open the service and change the user on the register "logon".

Or use the option -user from javaservice.exe:

> **-user user_name (optional)** - Specify the Windows domain username to be used when running the service (also requires that the password
>   parameter is specified). Local user accounts are specified as
>   .\user_name whereas domain accounts may be specified as either
>   domain\user_name or user_name@domain (the latter form has been
>   required on some systems to avoid reports of 'I/O Operation in
>   progress' errors).

I strongly suggest to read the above link.

Comment: \\server_web\\Covers isn't a relative path. Anyway I am using the path parameter to define a additional path. (-path extra_path (optional))

Comment: By using \\ within a string you have \ only and on windows this is relative. Or Your Service does not have the privileges to access this resource.